# Formula is not working because of '#N/A'

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am writing a simple formula like

```
 =IF(G295="#N/A","NA","Somethingelse")
```

But it's not printing 'NA' only when I give this value "#N/A" If I use the above formula for

```
 =IF(G295="R","NA","Somethingelse")
```

Then it's working. Can anyone help me how to reconize this value "#N/A"? I need to write the formular like if this value (#N/A) presents, then I have to do some other operation, Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ISNA` function will identify `#N/A`

```
=IF(ISNA(G295),"NA","Somethingelse")
```

Unlike `ISERROR`, it only catches `#N/A`

Answer (score 1):

```
=IFERROR(IF(G295="Y","Yes","No"),"NA")
```

will capture error (N/A) and write out "NA", else it will look for Y or N.